# How many different concepts of "token equivalence" are there in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, programming, big-list

I was living in the delusion that the "token equality" tested by `\ifx` was the only thing you need to remember about this subject, but this week I learned otherwise (thanks to David Carlisle).

Now I'm wondering how many fundamentally different concepts of "token equivalence" there are?

So far I know two:

1. Test with `\ifx`.

   Two characters are equal when they have the same character code and catcode, two cs names are equal when they are both undefined or are both "let to the same thing", a cs name is equal to a character iff it has been `\let` to it, ...
2. Test in delimited argument.

   Two characters are equal when they have the same character code and catcode, two cs names are equal when they *have the same name*, a character is never equal to a cs name, ...

But my knowledge is obviously fragmentary. I'd like to have the whole picture.

It's hard to find out about such things in the TeXbook.

I'd like to ask for one answer per fundamentally different concept of token equality.

Each answer should specify

- In what context this concept is invoked.
- Which tokens are equal and which are not.
- Is this arbitrary or is there a rationale behind this (as opposed to making everything work as with `\ifx`).
- Is there any neat trick with which this can be exploited?

**Just to be sure:** I'd also like answers on the two examples I mentioned, as my knowledge is obviously limited...

Comment: There is `\if` equality (characters compared by character code, all csnames are equal)

Comment: Yes I was going to mention that also, but left it out for the moment as it will expand expandable things, but yes, it should probably be included although it will be tricky to describe (`\if a\noexpand\a`). Please write an answer on it ;-)

Comment: see "TeX for the Impatient" p. 236, available with TeXLive

Comment: @Herbert That explains `\ifx` and is as far as I can see equivalent with the explanation in the TeXbook. I think `\ifx` is probably the least mysterious token equivalence test, and everybody will more or less be aware of this definition. But maybe there are some secrets even here?

Comment: Small secret: `\ifx` compares macros by their first level expansion, using the same rules it uses for argument delimiters; in particular it compares control sequences by name and not by their meaning.

Comment: chapter 13 of "[tex by topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html)" covers conditionals in detail.  the cited examples are the only ones i saw on quick inspection that test for "token equality", but it's still worthwhile to use this resource for fuller understanding of the concepts -- everything is there in one place.

Comment: @egreg I think I read somewhere that macro expansions which are equal are stored only once and `\ifx` only compares the memory locations. Your explanation would follow from this, but it would make the effort for comparing O(1) in contrast to really comparing the first level expansions...

Comment: I'm not an expert in "TeX the program", but I feel it would be very slow looking through the equivalence table each time a `\def` is executed. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @egreg You're right. I just tested it and blew main memory with 100000 macros having the same expansion text. Another long-standing delusion destroyed! I wonder whether `\ifx` is faster in comparing when both macros have been `\let` to each other...

Comment: I guess so: they share the same memory location, so the check is easy. I believe that TeX first checks the memory location.

Comment: @egreg Yes, there is a comment somewhere that since amstex often does `\let\a\b...\ifx\a\b` Knuth added that optimization.

Comment: See also: [macros - How do I examine a token? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/how-do-i-examine-a-token)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best way to think about it is that the “basic equality” of tokens is that character tokens are equal if they have same character code and catcode. command tokens are equal if they have the same name.

Then delimited macro parsing requires equal tokens.

`\ifx` tests if the  “definition” of the two tokens is equal. Where for a macro the definition is the list of tokens in its definition (first level expansion) for a primitive each primitive has a unique definition and for a character token (and command tokens let to a character token) the definition encapsulates the character and catcode.

`\if` differs from `\ifx` in the way it uses expansion to determine the tokens to be tested but apart from that, it uses a modified form of equality where only the character code not catcode is considered for character tokens and all command tokens not `\let` to character tokens are considered equal.

`\ifcat` is the same as `\if` except it uses the catcode not the character code.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I learned a lot of new things. I hope I have the whole picture now ;-)

Answer (score 6):

*⟨token 1⟩* is the same as *⟨token 2⟩* if with
`\newtoks\Scratchtoks` and
`\Scratchtoks{⟨token 1⟩}\edef\tempa{\the\Scratchtoks}` and
`\Scratchtoks{⟨token 2⟩}\edef\tempb{\the\Scratchtoks}` and
`\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` and
`\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}`
the test
`\ifx\tempa\tempb\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi`
yields
`\firstoftwo`.

Pitfalls/Problems:

This test is not expandable as temporary assignments (`\Scratchtoks`, `\tempa` and `\tempb`) are required.
*⟨token 1⟩* and/or *⟨token 2⟩* being defined in terms of `\outer` is a problem.
*⟨token 1⟩* and/or *⟨token 2⟩* being an explicit character token of catcode 1 or 2 is a problem.

---

`\ifx⟨token 1⟩⟨token 2⟩...` tests if *⟨token 1⟩* and *⟨token 2⟩* have the same meaning.

`\if⟨token 1⟩⟨token 2⟩...` tests if *⟨token 1⟩* and *⟨token 2⟩* have the same character code. Expandable tokens are expanded while gathering *⟨token 1⟩* and *⟨token 2⟩*. Undefined *⟨control sequence tokens⟩* yield error-messages `! Undefined control sequence.` unless their expansion is prevented via preceding them with `\noexpand` in which case they are treated like unexpandable control sequence tokens that are not implicit character tokens. All unexpandable control sequence tokens that are not implicit character tokens are assumed to have the same character code—a character code which no character has. With implicit characters, be they control symbol tokens or control word tokens or active character tokens, the character code of the character token is assumed which they are let equal to. Active characters that are undefined are assumed to have the character code of their non-active pendants if preceded by `\noexpand`.

`\ifcat⟨token 1⟩⟨token 2⟩...` tests if *⟨token 1⟩* and *⟨token 2⟩* have the same category code. Expandable tokens are expanded while gathering *⟨token 1⟩* and *⟨token 2⟩*.  Undefined *⟨control sequence tokens⟩* yield error-messages `! Undefined control sequence.` unless their expansion is prevented via preceding them with `\noexpand` in which case they are treated like unexpandable control sequence tokens that are not implicit character tokens. All unexpandable control sequence tokens that are not implicit character tokens are assumed to have the same category code—a category code which no character has. With implicit characters, be they control symbol tokens or control word tokens or active character tokens, the category code of the character token is assumed which they are let equal to. Active characters that are undefined are assumed to have category code 13(active) if preceded by `\noexpand`.

---

Control symbol tokens and control word tokens are equal if they have the same name. I.e., if applying `\string` yields the same sequence of character tokens.

Except for some edge cases:

The nameless control sequence token can be created in two ways:

1. Via `\csname\endcsname`.
2. Via a single character of category code 0 (escape), i.e.,  `\`, at the end of a line of .tex-input while the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar` is not within the range of possible coding-points for characters.

Applying `\string` to the nameless control sequence yields a sequence of character-tokens:

```
⟨current escapechar-token⟩c12s12n12a12m12e12⟨current escapechar-token⟩e12n12d12c12s12n12a12m12e12
```

`⟨current escapechar-token⟩`  denotes no token at all/nothing in case of the integer-parameter `\escapechar` not being within the range of possible coding-points for characters.

In case of the integer-parameter `\escapechar` being within the range of possible coding-points for characters `⟨current escapechar-token⟩`  denotes a character token whose character code equals the value of `\escapechar` and whose category code is 10(space) in case of `\ecapechar` having the value 32 and whose category code is 12(other) in case of the value of `\ecsapechar` differing from 32.

Thus with `\string` alone you cannot distinguish the nameless control sequence from the control-word-token whose name is
`csname⟨character denoted by current value of \escapechar⟩endcsname`.

In the edge case of these two tokens having been assigned the same meaning, `\ifx` also is not suitable for distinguishing them.

You can distinguish them

- by means of delimited arguments.
- by defining temporary macros and `\ifx`-comparing them.

The following example

```
\expandafter\def\csname\endcsname{Some Definition.}

\begingroup
\def\firstofone#1{#1}
\catcode`\/=0
\catcode`\\=11
/firstofone{%
   /endgroup
   /def/csname\endcsname{Some Definition.}%
}%

\endlinechar=-1\relax

\message{^^J^^JStringification:^^J}
\message{^^J|\string\
|}
\message{^^J|\expandafter\string\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname|}
\message{^^JMeaning:^^J}
\message{^^J\meaning\
}
\message{^^J\expandafter\meaning\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname}
\message{^^JDirect \string\ifx-comparison:^^J}
\message{^^JTokens have %
\expandafter\ifx\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname\
equal meaning\else different meanings\fi.}
\message{^^J\string\ifx-comparison of temporary macros:}
\def\tempa{\
}%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname}%
\message{^^JTemporary macros defined from tokens have \ifx\tempa\tempb
equal meaning\else different meanings\fi.}
\message{^^J}
\csname stop\endcsname

\bye
```

yields the following messages on the terminal:

```
Stringification:
 
|\csname\endcsname| 
|\csname\endcsname|

Meaning:
 
macro:->Some Definition. 
macro:->Some Definition.

Direct \ifx-comparison:
 
Tokens have equal meaning.

\ifx-comparison of temporary macros:

Temporary macros defined from tokens have different meanings.
```

---

Character tokens are equal if they have the same category code and the same character code.

The crucial part is finding out whether a token is a control word token/control symbol token or an explicit character token.

This is crucial because there are edge cases.

E.g., you cannot distinguish an active character token let equal to one of its non-active pendants from that non-equal pendant other than by either using an argument delimited by one of those tokens or defining temporary macros as shown above.

E.g., after

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\a=13
\@firstofone{\endgroup\let a=}a
```

distinguishing active-a from catcode-11(letter)-a is possible only by either using an argument delimited by one of those tokens or defining temporary macros as shown above.

The same applies to one-letter-control-words/symbols while `\escapechar` has a negative value.

E.g., with

```
\escapechar=-1\relax
\let\a=a
```

distinguishing `\a` from catcode-11(letter)-a is possible only by either using an argument delimited by one of those tokens or defining temporary macros as shown above.
Alternatively you could exploit the fact that while `a` has the category code 11(letter) `\a` is not a control symbol token but a control word token and that therefore unexpanded-writing `\a` yields a sequence with a space-character following the `a` while unexpanded-writing `a` yields a sequence with no space-character following the `a`. If in between the catcode of a is switched to something else, e.g. 12(other), then this does not work out because then `\a` is a control symbol token and TeX does not append space characters when unexpanded-writing a control symbol token.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer!

We need this kind of in-depth studies which extend the existing documentation.

Starting bounty now...

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thank you for your kind comment but my answer was not that brillant. I saw the need of revising and editing it once more. ;-(   All these things can be found in (small subordinate clauses of) the TeXbook. ;-)   They can also be found in usenet postings to comp.text.tex/de.comp.text.tex of people like Donald Arseneau and David Kastrup (to name just two of the many persons to whom I owe gratitude for their explanations...)